# Google Chart: tooltips that display current column value with multiple hidden column value using dataview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts, google-visualization

I am a newbie to this field and would like to learn more to improvise myself.I working on google chart with dynamic data using asp.net and oracle.

Everything was fine up until tooltips area where I need to hide 2 column from chart area after load their data from oracle to google datatable but displaying all their information and values inside one remaining column as tooltip.

Here is an overview what I'm trying to accomplish.
[tooltip with hidden column information and value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6OhF.png)

Here the code that generate the chart:

```
   str.Append(@"<script type=text/javascript>google.charts.load( *current*, { callback: function(){ 

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'External System');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Data Completeness(%)');");

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            str.Append(@"data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
               data.addRows([['', 0, 'No Data To Display For This Month']]);
                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
                    chart.draw(data, { height: 530, width: 1300, colors:['#bc001f'] , annotations: { stem: { color: 'transparent', length: 180 }, textStyle: { color: '#000000', fontSize: 19, bold: true}}, bar: {groupWidth: '95%'}, legend: { textStyle: { fontSize: 15, bold:true}},  hAxis: {title: 'External Systems', titleTextStyle: {color: '#b20c0c',fontSize: 23,bold:true}, textStyle: { fontSize: 15, bold:true, color: '#000000',}}, vAxis: { viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 30}, textStyle: { fontSize: 15, bold:true, color: '#000000',}},backgroundColor: 'transparent'});");

        }

        else
        {
            str.Append(@"data.addColumn('number', 'Asset Count ');
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Asset Count ');");
            str.Append("data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");


            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["EXT_SYSTEM_NAME"].ToString() + "');");
                str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["DB_COMPLETENESS"].ToString() + ") ;");
                str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 2 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT"].ToString() + "');");
                str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 3 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["AVAILABLE_IN_GIS"].ToString() + "');");


            }


            str.Append("var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({suffix:'%'});");
            str.Append("formatter.format(data, 1);");
            str.Append("var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);");
            str.Append("view.setColumns([0, 1,{ role: 'annotation',type: 'string',calc: 'stringify',  sourceColumn: 1}]); ");

            str.Append(@"var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            var options = {width: 1300, height: 530, chartArea: { top: 75}, colors:['#bc001f', '#ff8a16', '#3650af'] , focusTarget: 'category', animation: { startup: true, duration: 2200, easing: 'linear'} ,backgroundColor: 'transparent', legend: { alignment: 'center', textStyle: { fontSize: 15, bold:true}}, annotations: { stem: { color: 'transparent'}, alwaysOutside: true, 
textStyle: {
  fontName: 'Times-Roman',
  fontSize: 18,
  bold: true,
  color: '#000000',


        }
        },
        hAxis: { title: 'Type of External', titleTextStyle: {color: '#7324c1',fontSize: 25,bold:true}, textStyle: { fontSize: 15, bold:true, color: '#000000',}},
        vAxis: { title: 'Completeness(%)', titleTextStyle: {color: '#7324c1',fontSize: 25,bold:true}, textStyle: { fontSize: 15, bold:true, color: '#000000',}}

        };


        chart.draw(view, options); ");
        }
   str.Append("},packages: ['corechart']});");





        str.Append("</script>");
```

I'm using Dataview to display the column 0 and 1 while hiding column 2 and 3 but i would like to display information of column 2 and 3 along with column 1 inside column 1 tooltip dynamically.I don't know how to accomplish this.

Can you please give me a hand?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a tooltip column would be similar to adding the annotation column you already have

annotation --> `{role: 'annotation', type: 'string', calc: 'stringify', sourceColumn: 1}`

but you can provide your own `calc` function, instead of `'stringify'`
(`sourceColumn` isn't needed here)

```
dataView.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: buildTooltip,
  p: {html: true},
  role: 'tooltip',
  type: 'string'
}]);
```

the function you define will receive arguments for the data table and row index,
which you can use to pull values for any column...

```
function buildTooltip(dt, row) {
  var tooltip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><div><span>';
  tooltip += dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + '</span></div>';
  tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(1) + ':&nbsp;';
  tooltip += '<span>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + '</span></div>';
  tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(2) + ':&nbsp;';
  tooltip += '<span>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + '</span></div>';
  tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(3) + ':&nbsp;';
  tooltip += '<span>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3) + '</span></div></div>';
  return tooltip;
}
```

two things are needed to use custom tooltips,
1) the column must have a property for --> `html: true`
2) the options should include --> `tooltip: {isHtml: true}`

one issue, there is a bug or something, where the data view ignores column properties when drawing the chart, so the tooltip displays the html tags, instead of the content
when drawing the chart, convert the view back to a data table...

```
chart.draw(dataView.toDataTable(), options);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Data');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Y0');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Y2');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Y3');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Y4');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Y5');
  dataTable.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 04, 02, 13, 01, 25, 00), 100, 100, 38.6, 100, 38.6, 89],
    [new Date(2017, 04, 02, 13, 32, 33, 00), 97, 92, 55.6, 100, 46.6, 89],
    [new Date(2017, 04, 02, 14, 00, 01, 00), 75, 89, 45.8, 88, 55.5, 89],
    [new Date(2017, 04, 02, 14, 35, 07, 00), 68, 75, 57.9, 99, 33.1, 89]
  ]);

  var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
  });
  date_formatter.format(dataTable, 0);

  var viewColumns = [0];
  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
  dataView.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: buildTooltip,
    p: {html: true},
    role: 'tooltip',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  function buildTooltip(dt, row) {
    var tooltip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><div><span>';
    tooltip += dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + '</span></div>';
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(1) + ':&nbsp;';
    tooltip += '<span>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + '</span></div>';
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(2) + ':&nbsp;';
    tooltip += '<span>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + '</span></div>';
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(3) + ':&nbsp;';
    tooltip += '<span>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3) + '</span></div></div>';
    return tooltip;
  }

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      title: '(%)',
      viewWindow: {
        min:0,
        max: 120
      }
    },
    legend: {position: 'top'},
    pointSize: 8,
    tooltip: {isHtml: true}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataView.toDataTable(), options);
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```